# How can I do this block in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I do like this in beamer[image]

This is my code in R sweave

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor={svgnames},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\definecolor{aggiemaroon}{RGB}{80,0,0} 
\usecolortheme[named=aggiemaroon]{structure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext]{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning,shadows,trees,decorations.markings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{209,23,23}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,153,51}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{102,0,102}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{%
    empty,
    coltitle = #1,
    title = #2,
    overlay ={
        \draw[mygrey,line width=1pt]
        (frame.north west)--(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--(frame.south west)--(frame.north west);
        \draw[#1,line width=1pt]
        ($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
        --(frame.north west)
        --($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
        \draw[#1,line width=1pt]
        ($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
        --(frame.south east)
        --($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
    }
}
\tcbset{marktext/.style={%
        overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};},
        code={\setbox\z@=\color@hbox#1\color@endbox\tcbdimto\myheight{\wd\z@+3mm}},
        minimum for equal height group=\tcb@ehgid:\myheight,
}}

\makeatletter
 
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{% 
\beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{% 
\gdef\insertframetitle{\centering{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}% 
\gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}% 
\gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}% 
            }% 
          } 
\newenvironment{noheadline}{
\setbeamertemplate{noheadline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vpace*{-0.9\○baselineskip}}{}
          }{}
\makeatother 
\title[Master Economie appliquée]{Test de point de changement CUSUM pour les séries financières basées sur SVR}
\author [Chaymae HAFID ]{Chaymae HAFID}
\date[ \today]{\today}
\institute{\textbf{Encadré par: Pr. ALJ $\&$ Pr .TOUIJAR}} 
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ghuf.PNG}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{Table de matières}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
 \begin{frame}[fragile]{This is a \texttt{fragile} frame}
\begin{block}{This is a R chunk}
<<oneandone>>=
 1+1
@
\end{block}
 \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=3,
    raster equal height=rows
    ]
\begin{mybox}{myred}{Title 1}
                some text in the first box
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{myorange}{Title 2}
some text in the second box
some text in the second box
some text in the second box
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{mypurple}{Title 3}
                some text in the third box blabla
\end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I have errors like : ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "this"? The colored headings, the font, ...? Please explain your issue better ...

Comment: Please show some code of yours, so that we know about your intended set up (theme etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the tcolorbox package :[image]

I used the following code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster}

\makeatletter

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{209,23,23}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,153,51}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{102,0,102}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{200,200,200}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{%
empty,
coltitle = #1,
title = #2,
overlay ={
\draw[mygrey,line width=1pt]
(frame.north west)--(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--(frame.south west)--(frame.north west);
\draw[#1,line width=1pt]
($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
--(frame.north west)
--($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
\draw[#1,line width=1pt]
($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
--(frame.south east)
--($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
}
}

\tcbset{marktext/.style={%
  overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};},
  code={\setbox\z@=\color@hbox#1\color@endbox\tcbdimto\myheight{\wd\z@+3mm}},
  minimum for equal height group=\tcb@ehgid:\myheight,
  }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=3,
    raster equal height=rows
    ]
    \begin{mybox}{myred}{Title 1}
    some text in the first box
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{myorange}{Title 2}
    some text in the second box
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{mypurple}{Title 3}
    some text in the third box blabla
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in texstudio but when I add it in my R sweave code , it gives me some errors           you can find my code  in the question